# Method if condition logic

Tags: c#

This logic checks `accessGroup` and if `accessGroup` is equal to "Admin" then it only checks if `result.Admin` or `baccess` is true but if accessGroup is anything else it will need to check two other objects `result.Admin == true || result.PowerUser`.
Is there any other way to do this if condition?

```cs
if (accessGroup == "Admin")
{
  if (baccess == true || result.Admin == true)
  {
    var FileInfo = GetFile(fileManagerGuidId);
    if (FileInfo != null)
    {
      FileManagerLog _filemanagerLog = new FileManagerLog();
      _filemanagerLog.CustomerId =Request.Cookies["customerid"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["customerid"].Value) : 0;
      _filemanagerLog.FileManagerGuid = new Guid(fileManagerGuidId);
      SaveFileManagerLog(_filemanagerLog);
      byte[] fileBytes = FileInfo.FileData;
      return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileInfo.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
else
{
  if (baccess == true || result.Admin == true || result.PowerUser)
  {
    var FileInfo = GetFile(fileManagerGuidId);
    if (FileInfo != null)
    {
      FileManagerLog _filemanagerLog = new FileManagerLog();
      _filemanagerLog.CustomerId =Request.Cookies["customerid"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["customerid"].Value) : 0;
      _filemanagerLog.FileManagerGuid = new Guid(fileManagerGuidId);
      SaveFileManagerLog(_filemanagerLog);
      byte[] fileBytes = FileInfo.FileData;
      return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileInfo.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to refactor your code, 90%+ of provided code is duplicated. If you clean repeated code up, it will be much easier for you to find a way to optimize the `if` condition.

Comment: probably better to ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like you want `if(baccess == true || result.Admin == true || (accessGroup != "Admin" && result.PowerUser))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Enum flags is really great in ur case,
create an enum with

```
admin = 1 
poweruser = 2
normaluser = 4
```

and check on the result you have
"== true" is useless, writing the boolean itself is enough

```
if (baccess|| result.Admin || result.PowerUser)
```

second solution :
if powerUse is only for normal user, you can use Or state

Answer (score 1):

```
Boolean allowed = false;
if (baccess || result.Admin)
{
    if (accessGroup == "Admin")
    {
        allowed = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        allowed =result.PowerUser
    }
}

if(allowed)
{
    var FileInfo = GetFile(fileManagerGuidId);
    if (FileInfo == null)
    {

         FileManagerLog _filemanagerLog = new FileManagerLog();
        _filemanagerLog.CustomerId =Request.Cookies["customerid"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["customerid"].Value) : 0;
        _filemanagerLog.FileManagerGuid = new Guid(fileManagerGuidId);
        SaveFileManagerLog(_filemanagerLog);
        byte[] fileBytes = FileInfo.FileData;
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileInfo.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: good attempt but a little overly complicated i've cleaned it up, though you have changed to logic the op added, but i think you have done what they meant to do

Comment: good improvement!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this some better than others

however looking at the logic i think you can drop most of it
as you are ORing all the fields then

- if they have bacess the code runs regardless of anything else
- if they
  have result.Admin the code runs regardless of anything else
- if they
  have accessGroup == "Admin" the code runs regardless of anything else
- if they have result.PowerUser the code runs regardless of anything
  else

the only way this code wont run is if !baccess & !result.Admin & !result.PowerUser & accessGroup != "Admin"

so this is exactly the same

```
if (baccess  || result.Admin || (accessGroup != "Admin"  &&  Result.PowerUser))
{
    var FileInfo = GetFile(fileManagerGuidId);
    if (FileInfo != null)
    {
        FileManagerLog _filemanagerLog = new FileManagerLog();
        _filemanagerLog.CustomerId =Request.Cookies["customerid"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["customerid"].Value) : 0;
        _filemanagerLog.FileManagerGuid = new Guid(fileManagerGuidId);
        SaveFileManagerLog(_filemanagerLog);
        byte[] fileBytes = FileInfo.FileData;
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileInfo.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

though i suspect you actually wanting to AND (&&) the fields together
which would look like

```
if (baccess  &&  (result.Admin || (accessGroup != "Admin" && result.PowerUser))
```

ie if they have access and are an admin or a poweruser

Comment: I'm a little confuse If `result.PowerUser True` but accessGroup is admin would that process into the if statement. That is saying the users has rights of PowerUser but the data access is admin

Comment: if they had baccess yes it would

Comment: @Jefferson had slightly misread so done a slight rejig to correct